# json_serializable - Add a generic field to a freezed/json_serializable class

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed, json-serializable, flutter-freezed

How do I make a [Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) object take a generic type? I want to do this:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/entity_types/option_entity.dart';

part 'vegan_item_tag.freezed.dart';
part 'vegan_item_tag.g.dart';

@freezed
abstract class VeganItemTag<T>
    with _$VeganItemTag<T>
    implements OptionEntity<T> {
  const factory VeganItemTag({int? iconCodePoint, T? id, String? name}) =
      _VeganItemTag;

  const VeganItemTag._();

  factory VeganItemTag.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$VeganItemTagFromJson(json);
}
```

I've tried using `@With.fromString('AdministrativeArea<House>')` from the docs but can't apply it correctly to this class.

One of the errors:

> lib/src/common/enums/tags/common/vegan_item_tag.freezed.dart:142:32:
> Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
> *$*$_VeganItemTagFromJson(json);

Think I might be on the right track with this, but it no longer generates a `vegan_item_tag.g.dart` file:

```
@freezed
abstract class VeganItemTag<T>
    with _$VeganItemTag<T>
    implements OptionEntity<T> {
  const factory VeganItemTag(
      {required int iconCodePoint,
      required T id,
      required String name}) = _VeganItemTag;

  const VeganItemTag._();

  factory VeganItemTag.fromJson(
    Map<String, Object?> json,
    T Function(Object?) fromJsonT,
  ) => VeganItemTag(
      iconCodePoint: json['iconCodePoint'] as int,
      id: fromJsonT(json['id']),
      name: json['name'] as String,
    );
}
```

Comment: I saw no errors. I ran `  var tag = VeganItemTag<String>(id: '');
  print(tag.id.runtimeType);` and got String so the type information does not seems to be lost. Is there something from the question im missing?

Comment: @croxx5f I just get heaps of errors when I view the debug console. Do you not?

Comment: @croxx5f `lib/src/common/enums/tags/common/vegan_item_tag.freezed.dart:142:32: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
      _$_$_VeganItemTagFromJson(json);
`

Comment: I think the errors are json ones so omitting the json would not show the errors, but I need the json

Comment: Yes, the problem seems isolated to the fromJson constructor. And for some reason I can't even generate the example model (of the package readme) .g.dart file when running the build-runner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several solutions to this problem. But in all of them you need to explicitly convert your classes to a generic type Firebase can handle such as `String` or `Map<dynamic, String>`.

The 3 ways to implement such behavior are:

### FromJson ToJson

This is messier to maintain than `JsonConverters` on complex scenarios so I would discard this option for your solution.

### JsonConverters

It works for automatizing conversions of specific classes or abstract classes through inheritance, but from generic types with different data to store it may not be what you require. If you are always saving the same values from the generic type `T` you may try to use this solution through implemented abstract classes.

### GenericArgumentFactories

This is what you are actually asking about. Working with [genericArgumentFactories](https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonSerializable/genericArgumentFactories.html) on [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) and [Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) is not easy and I found a bug on [Freezed package](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) meanwhile.

But I managed to get this code working which is the actual solution .

```dart
@freezed
@JsonSerializable(genericArgumentFactories: true)
class VeganItemTagV2<T> with _$VeganItemTagV2<T> {
  const VeganItemTagV2._();

  const factory VeganItemTagV2({
    required int iconCodePoint,
    required T id,
    required String name,
  }) = _VeganItemTag<T>;

  //It only works with block bodies and not with expression bodies
  //I don't know why
  factory VeganItemTagV2.fromJson(
      Map<String, dynamic> json, T Function(Object? json) fromJsonT) {
    return _$VeganItemTagV2FromJson<T>(json, fromJsonT);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(Object Function(T value) toJsonT) {
    return _$VeganItemTagV2ToJson<T>(this, toJsonT);
  }
}
```

This adds the converters on the `toJson` and `fromJson` methods to be used depending on the generic type.

NOTE. These methods can't be expressions for some bug as it doesn't compile but it works with block bodies. [Freezed does not oficcially support it](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/issues/463) so you may consider creating this class without Freezed package.

This is a example with an encapsulated class of a `String` and a test class to see how it works:

```dart
class VeganId {
  final String id;

  VeganId(this.id);

  String itemId() {
    return id;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'VeganId{id: $id}';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is VeganId && runtimeType == other.runtimeType && id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

And the test which works fine

```dart
  test('veganItemV2 from and toJson', () {
    final dto = VeganItemTagV2<VeganId>(
      iconCodePoint: 1,
      id: VeganId("veganID"),
      name: "name",
    );

    final Map<String, dynamic> actualToJson = dto.toJson((id) => id.itemId());

    expect(actualToJson, {"iconCodePoint": 1, "id": "veganID", "name": "name"});

    final VeganItemTagV2 actualFromJson = VeganItemTagV2<VeganId>.fromJson(
      actualToJson,
      (json) =>
        VeganId(json as String),
    );

    expect(actualFromJson, dto);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last code doesn't generate the `vegan_item_tag.g.dart` because you wrote a wrong code in the `VeganItemTag.fromJson` factory. Edit it to be something like this:

```
factory VeganItemTag.fromJson(
    Map<String, Object?> json,
    T Function(Object?) fromJsonT,
  ) => _$VeganItemTagFromJson(json, fromJsonT);
```

Or:

```
factory VeganItemTag.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) =>
    _$VeganItemTagFromJson(json);
```

And then re-run the `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` command.

Comment: Thanks. _$VeganItemTagFromJson is expecting one positional argument